# PHP - Opening Hours

Tags: php, time

I'm trying to run a script that'll show a message in opening hours of the business, However it seems to not work when going overnight eg 11pm-4am, Any idea how I can resolve it? Current code is below:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+0'); 

// Define daily open hours. Must be in 24-hour format, separated by dash. If closed for the day, set to 00:00-00:00
$time_range_mon = '23:00-04:00';
$time_range_tue = '23:00-04:00';
$time_range_wed = '23:00-04:00';
$time_range_thu = '23:00-04:00';
$time_range_fri = '23:00-04:00';
$time_range_sat = '23:00-04:00';
$time_range_sun = '23:00-04:00';

// Gets current day of week
$status_today = strtolower(date("D"));
// Gets current time of day in 00:00 format
$current_time = date("G:i");
// Makes current time of day computer-readable
$current_time_x = strtotime($current_time);

// Builds an array, assigning user-defined time ranges to each day of week
$all_days = array("mon" => $time_range_mon, "tue" => $time_range_tue, "wed" =>     $time_range_wed, "thu" => $time_range_thu, "fri" => $time_range_fri, "sat" =>     $time_range_sat, "sun" => $time_range_sun);
foreach ($all_days as &$each_day) {
    $each_day = explode("-", $each_day);
    $each_day[0] = strtotime($each_day[0]);
    $each_day[1] = strtotime($each_day[1]);
}

// Defines array of possible days of week
$week_days = array("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun");

// Compares current day of week to possible days of week and determines open vs closed     output based on current day and time.
foreach ($week_days as &$each_week_day) {
    if ($status_today == $each_week_day) {
        if (($all_days[$each_week_day][0] <= $current_time_x) &&     ($all_days[$each_week_day][1] >= $current_time_x)) {
        echo "Running Script - Operating Hours";
    } else {
        echo "Not Running Script - Out of Hours";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the funny `if ($status_today == $each_week_day)` comparison? Why not simply look up `$all_days[$status_today][0]` directly?

Comment: I've been having trouble with getting it to check overnight past few days, This is a version of a example online i found that does it (cutdown), Its only the bit checking overnight i'm trying to do then i'll put it back on my code just trying to get that working, would changing that resolve it do you think ?